# How To Move One Dive After Another Div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```html
<div class="test1">
    .........
 </div>
          
   <p>some text here</p>
            
 <div class="test2">
 </div>
```

I want to Move Div test1 after test2

Thanks

Comment: see jQuery's [after](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

Answer (score -2):

You can use Clone() function of jquery

```js
var divCopy = $('.test1').clone();
$('.test2').append(divCopy);
$('.test1:first').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test1">
    .........
 </div>
          
   <p>some text here</p>
            
 <div class="test2">
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you :) It Worked Perfectly!